# Trouble dynamically adding options to select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery-1.4.4.min.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        function click(){
            var select = document.getElementById("select");
            var json = [["Deutsch", "de-DE"], ["US Englisch", "en-US"]];
            json = JSON.parse(json);
            select.options.length = 0;
            for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++) {
                $("#select").append(new Option(json[i][0], json[i][1], false, false));
            }
        }   
    </script>

    <body>
        <select id="select"></select>
        <input type="button" onclick="click()" />
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to add options to the select element, but to no avail.

Comment: since you're really not using jQuery except for that one line, why not go straight JS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This won't work, because it isn't actually JSON data. It is a javascript Array:

```
var json = [["Deutsch", "de-DE"], ["US Englisch", "en-US"]];
   // json = JSON.parse(json);
   //    ^-----Eliminate the second line.
```

Also, you shouldn't use `click` for the method name. It will interfere in some browsers.

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/hdX84/

Comment: Thanks for the working example! It worked on jsfiddle, but when I copied the code verbatim, it didn't work. Are there any other issues at play here? I'm using chrome to test this.

Comment: @Joshua: Did you remember to change the name of the method in your inline `onclick` attribute? In the example I changed it from `click` to `click_me` since using `click` will fail in some browsers.

Comment: I replaced click with $(document).ready(...) for the option-adding-trigger.

Comment: @Joshua: I'm not sure what you mean. I still wouldn't use `click` as an identifier. Without seeing your actual code, I won't be able to tell what's wrong. I'd suggest you first test it with the inline attribute. By the way, if you placed the `click` function inside `$(document).ready()`, your inline attribute won't be able to see it. It needs to be `global`.

Answer (score 2):

i'd do

```
var mySel = $('#select')[0];
for(var i=0; i<json.length; i++){
        mySel.append(whatever);
    }
```

for more efficiency, because $('select') would always search through the DOM.
Doesn't really matter for 10 entries, but for large pages I'd try do efficient from
the start.

Comment: you can't call `append()` on a DOM object, that's a jQuery method. Doing the get `[0]` of the jQuery selector returns the DOM element

Comment: This also really should be posted as a comment since it doesn't deal with the issue at hand. I understand that you don't have enough rep to comment yet, but you still shouldn't abuse the Answers section. Since you only need 50 rep to comment, it shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
var json = [["Deutsch", "de-DE"], ["US Englisch", "en-US"]];
json = JSON.parse(json);
```

You don't have JSON. You have an **array of arrays**. It would only be JSON if it was enclosed in single quotes (i.e. if it was a string).

```
var data = [["Deutsch", "de-DE"], ["US Englisch", "en-US"]];
for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    $("#select").append($('<option />',{value: json[i][1], text: json[i][0]}));
}
```